# Using JS element in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I've a button inside a form:

```
 echo '<tr class="user-personal-info">';
     echo "<td><p>".$row['user_id']."</p></td>";
     echo "<td><input placeholder='Username' type='text' value='".$row['user_name']."'/></td>";
     echo "<td><input placeholder='Email' type='email' value='".$row['user_email']."'/></td>";  
                                            
     if($row['user_status'] == 1) {
         echo "<td><select>";
         echo "<option>User</option>";
         echo "<option>Admin</option>";
         echo "</select></td>";
     } else {
         echo "<td><select>";
         echo "<option>Admin</option>";
         echo "<option>User</option>";
         echo "</select></td>";
     }  
     echo "<td><input id='delete_btn' onclick='deleteUser(this);' type='submit' value='Delete'/></td>";
 echo '</tr>';
```

As you can see there is a click event on the button. When i hit the button the following javascript function is executed. `ID` containes the id of a specific row (`$row['user_id']`):

```
function deleteUser(deze) {
const ID = deze.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].innerText

$.ajax({
    url: "./includes/delete_user.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {id:ID},
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
  
}
```

I want to send this ID variable to PHP to delete that specific record that matches with the ID. The problem is that my `ID` from JS is not send to PHP. When i echo this in PHP i get following error: `Notice: Undefined index: id in...`.

PHP code:

```
<?php
include_once('./conn.php');
session_start();

$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id; //can't echo this variable sent from javascript...

?>
```

Comment: "i get following error:" — Where? In the `alert()`?

Comment: @Quentin No in the php file which i call with ajax: `delete_user.php` .

Comment: @DarkFelcore: So then you're seeing that error in the PHP logs?  In your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors at all on the console?  In the network tab of those tools, is that AJAX request made?  What data does it contain?  What is the server's response?

Comment: @David In my console there isn't any error. In the network tab i can see that an AJAX request is made (status = 200). The request does not contain any parameters and the response returns the error i mentioned above...

Comment: You used a submit button, but you nglected to cancel the default event action - so this will try to make your AJAX request, but then submits the form _the normal way_ right after your function is run, which cancels the running AJAX request. And since you are reading the ID value from a text node only, there is no way the normal form submission transports that same data value.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks that was my misktake thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put your `submit` button in a `<form>`, so after the JavaScript runs (but before the Ajax response is back and you `alert` it) the browser navigates to a new page (killing the JS program that is waiting for the response).

It is the new page that is showing the error and not the Ajax response.

Don't use `type="submit"` if you don't want to submit a form.

Use `type="button"`.

Comment: Super! That was my mistake